# how to work with different resolution in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have to prepare one application.I want give support to different resolution.i have to prepared different layouts.Frist time my layouts is,

```
res/layout/mylayout----7" normal screen
res/layout-large/mylayout----7" large screen
res/layout-xlarge/mylayout---10.1"
```

but it is taking 7" large screen.i found some solution in this site.Solution is ,create layout is,

```
res/layout/mylayout----7" normal screen
res/layout-sw600dp/mylayout----7" large screen
res/layout-sw720/mylayout---10.1"
```

After changed layout names it is taking 7" large screen only. please help me do.

Comment: You have to support densities and screen sizes. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: What device is using 7" large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project Build Target To support xlarge screen your project build target should be atleast android 2.3.3 adk.

In Eclipse -?right click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Select Project Build Tagrget as 2.3.3 or onwards.

First of all set the multiple screen support in your Android Application manifest file

```
<supports-screens                                 
    android:smallScreens="true"                    
    android:normalScreens="true"         
    android:largeScreens="true"            
    android:xlargeScreens="true"             
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

And also see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428096/design-layout-for-multiple-screens)

Comment: I have added in manifest file ,but when i have added android:xlargeScreens="true" in manifest file it is showing error.(version is 2.2)please help me

Comment: i have tried in 2.3.3 also,but it is taking only 7"large only

Answer (score 0):

```
 For mulitple screen support   Try by using this... in ur android manifest file
        <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
         />
```

Comment: Hi sandhya thanks for reply.I have used above part of code.But not working