# Android app background

Tags: android, background

when developing my app .. what size should I make the background ?
note that I want to make it for all four sized ( low , med , high , xhigh )

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428096/design-layout-for-multiple-screens) asked and answer here. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be below link help you

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to just provide a snip of some starting text  to indicate which part you're talking about and just to provide a relevant answer at a glance.

Comment: @ Kgrover have you read content of the page?? at bottom of page you can see the what i want to try to say