# android portrait and landscape layout design

Tags: android

as new to android creating two layout(layout and layout-land) folder for myapp.the both xml file is shown below.
 [image: Portrait layout for home page]

next landscape layout[image: Landscape layout for home page]

here is the manifest file in which some modification is done

[image: Manifest file of my app]

now the folder directory structure as i follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428096/design-layout-for-multiple-screens) in stackoverflow

i am not getting the correct look while tilting my mobile from portrait to landscape

is anything more i had to do to get the thing work correctly